# What is this small black rubber strip protruding out of the flap track fairing of the A320?

Tags: airbus-a320

On the Airbus A320 wing there in whilst in flight a small black rubber strip protruding out of the flap track fairing. What is it please?

[image: close up of a320 wing part flap track fairing.]

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be one of the rubber seals that are on the moveable flap track fairing.

[image: A320 flap track fairing seal]

<sup>[source](https://www.slideshare.net/BPancho/13-master-configuration-deviation-list-a320)</sup>

Since the fairing moves away from the wing it has probably come loose and is caught between the fairing and the flap.

I can't find a good photo of a fairing from an A320, but here is a photo of the fixed fairing from an A350. It's hard to tell if they are exactly the same, but you can see that they look similar.

[image: A350 flap track fairing]

<sup>[source](https://researchkonnection.com/ru/made-in-uae-summit-brings-together-the-best-in-manufacturing-industry/)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

I am a real world pilot and flying the A320 Family. The little black tube there isn't visible normally, but it looks like the main holders and calmer gum between the wing and movable equipment (Flaps, Spoilers, ...).
[image: You can see the black stripe at the right wing outer flap track fairing!]

You can see the black stripe at the right wing outer flap track fairing!

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE!